# Difference between CamelContext and Registry in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and bit confused between CamelContext and Registry.

As far as I know that CamelContext is the base object like ApplicationContext in Spring that is used for add routes and maintains the camel life cycle.

Also we got the Registry object from CamelContext but not sure what is the main purpose of this registry.

My intention is to add the component in the context/registry so that JNDIBind can look up the components.

Comment: I suggest to read chapter 1 of the Camel in Action book, it covers all these Camel main concepts to master - http://manning.com/ibsen/chapter1sample.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Claus Ibsen for the link

Answer (score 3):

**CamelContext:** Kind of Camel Runtime that keeps everything in Camel together, e.g.: Endpoints, TypeConverter, Routes, Components and Registry(!).

**Registry:** allows you to lookup beans, which by default will be JNDI beans. If you use the spring integration it will be Spring's ApplicationContext.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Generally **camel** when used with **spring** makes use of the **ApplicationContextRegistry** to lookup components, endpoints etc with the name of the bean defined in spring-bean.xml file. In places where we need to use JNDIRegistry we would have to add that registry when creating the CamelContext. This is used in places where JNDI objects are shared accross multiple JVMs where JNDI is the best solution.

Please see different types of registry implementation for camel: [camel registries](http://camel.apache.org/registry.html)